# Sample size/ power estimation for similarity index (Dice/ F1 Score)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, sample-size, statistical-power, similarities

We will start a study in order to validate an algorithm for image segmentation for medical use. We will use Dice Sorensen coefficient in order to measure the agreement/ similarity between the algorithm, and medical professionals.

Since there doesn't seem to be much published/ in the literature about this, I wanted to ask what others thought the best way of measuring the correct sample size to power the study would be with this endpoint.

What I have also been trying to take into account is:

1. presence of a segmented object in a given image - some images may not have anything to segment
2. the variability in the size of the object in each image. Assuming the image resolution is the same, smaller objects will be subject to lower Dice scores for similar error
3. Accounting for differences in disease severity/ healthy patients in the sample

It would seem that a stratified/ judgmental sampling approach may be appropriate in order to account for the difference in disease severity and size of objects.

I am struggling a bit to identify the best method to use to estimate sample size/ power given this endpoint.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have pilot data? And what statistical test do you plan to use in order to detect differences between machine and human expert?

Comment: yes we have some pilot data (validation) that we can use to test/ simulate. We will use bland altman and dice sorensen score as endpoints

Comment: I know "power" only in connection with tests - are you planning a statistical test (like https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-022-04739-2) or do you have a precise concept when you would consider the test criterion / data combination powerful enough? Having no out-of-the-box method to determine power, I would probably just simulate that situation that I want to be able to detect, and determine a sufficient sample size this way. It takes assumptions about the dependence structure to do that.

Comment: ok thanks, yes i will try to simluate something I think. in this case, I am happy to play with the magnitude of power, but we can assume 80% power with 0.05 alpha to be acceptable. For bland altman I can see there is a library called blandPower for this purpose, but for dice it seems there are no solutions out the box

Comment: Dice score is a measure of similary indicating how related two samples are. I had planned to put a target here of acceptance. Do you propose something else?

Comment: So you use Dice score directly as a test statistic - good :-) Where did you plan to get the target threshold from?

Comment: Is ground truth = medical experts segmentation? Do yoy have only one medical expert, or several looking at the same image?

Comment: yes it is the test statistic :) the threshold is hard to estimate, but comes from a combination of limits of the algorithm itself, and from accuracy of human graders (literature) and clinically meaningful measures. Ground truth will be 3 graders

Comment: Wow, three graders on each image? They probably differ a bit, don't they?

Comment: yes, they can differ quite a lot, but there is a general consensus which will be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Summary of the question, taking comments into account

[Sørensen-Dice index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dice.html) is used in image segmentation to assess the similarity between two segmentation results, in the present case manual segmentation by human experts, and automatic segmentation. It takes values between 0 and 1, where 0 means that there is no overlap between the detected areas, and 1 means complete overlap.

The planned study will try to use this index to assess if the segmentation results are good enough. According to the comments, the criterion is that some statistic that summarizes results from a number of images exceeds a certain threshold. Since the distribution of the index varies considerably depending on circumstances like resolution, or type of objects on the images, the study will be set up in strata. OP asks how to size the study in order to achieve a given power, which here refers to the probability that the summary statistics exceeds some given threshold $\vartheta$.

No information about the distribution of the index is available other than pilot data, that cover all strata.

##### Power calculation by normal approximation

An overall criterion to judge the quality of the algorithm could consist in a **weighted mean with weights depending on stratum**. This has the advantage that a normal approximation should be justifiable for relatively small sample sizes already, since the distribution of the original data is bounded. Of course, this requires independent sampling within strata.

Assume we have $k$ strata, with sampling proportions $\rho_1,\dots,\rho_k$, i.e., we sample $n_j=n\rho_j$ from stratum $j$. Let $x_{j i}$ denote the $i$-th value from stratum $j$, for $i=1,\dots,n_j$, and let $w_j$ be the weight for stratum $j$. The weighted mean,
$$
  \bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}w_j x_{ji}}{\sum_{j=1}^k n_j w_j},
$$
is approximately normal with mean and variance
$$
 \mu:= \mathbb{E} \bar{X} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^k \rho_j w_j \mu_j}{\sum_{j=1}^k \rho_j w_j}\quad\text{and}\quad \sigma^2 := \mathrm{Var} \bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} 
 \frac{\sum_{j=1}^k \rho_j w_j^2 \sigma_j^2}{(\sum_{j=1}^k \rho_j w_j)^2}.
$$
Here $\mu_j$ and $\sigma_j^2$ denote means and variances within stratum $j$. These quantities can be estimated from the pilot data.

The sample size $n$ that warrants at least a  probability $\beta$, that $\bar{X}$ exceeds the threshold $\vartheta$, where $\vartheta < \mu$, follows from
$$
  P(\bar{X} \geq \vartheta) \geq \beta \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad n\geq \sigma^2\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(1-\beta)}{\mu - \vartheta}\right)^2,
$$
where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the quantile function of the standard normal distribution.

One can plug in the estimated means and variances per stratum to get an estimate of the necessary sample size $n$.

**Caveat:** If the pilot study is small, around 10-20 per stratum, say, the estimated sample size will be quite unprecise. Use bootstrap with per stratum resampling to get an impression on the quality of this estimated sample size.

**Remark** as long as there is no null hypothesis, there is no type 1 error, and the threshold $\vartheta$ is arbitrary.